# Run python GUI application as service on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, systemctl

I've successfully manage to run my GUI python application as a service in a Raspberry pi. The used unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example systemd service.
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="Display=:0"
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/tf/
ExecStart=/home/pi/tf/myApp.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
KillMode=process
Timeout=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

At the beginning of my python application i added the route python3 like this:

```
#! /address/where/is/python3
```

The problem is that i can't do the same in Ubuntu.

I think is because .Xauthority file does not exist. 
In ubuntu i ran

```
echo $XAUTHORITY
```

and i got:

```
/run/user/1000/Xauthority
```

then i change these lines:

```
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/Xauthority
WorkingDirectory=/home/sergio/tf/
ExecStart=/home/sergio/tf/myApp.py
```

with "journalctl -u myApp -f" displays the following error:

```
cannot connect to X server
```

Any idea what can it be?

Comment: hello @sergio-omar-martinez-garcia, had you get the solution for the same? I am facing the same issue with pyQT4 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: in your service file try:
Environment="Display=:0"
Environment="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1"
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/yourusername/.Xauthority

Comment: I have changed to this but it is still showing "can not connect to X server"

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by following the steps by htorque in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/21923/how-do-i-create-the-xauthority-file

Follow this steps:

> 1-Open System > Preferences > Startup Applications
>
> 2-Click on Add :
>
> 3-Name: Xauthority
>
> 4-Command: /bin/bash -c 'ln -s -f "$XAUTHORITY"
>   ~/.Xauthority' Comment: Creates a symbolic link from ~/.Xauthority to
>   $XAUTHORITY and add the entry by clicking on Add.
>
> Now every time you log in, it should create the link to the current
>   authority file.

So now we have the file .Xauthority in ~/ 
Finally service file myApp.service was updated like this:

> Environment="Display=:0" 
>          Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/"yourUsername"/.Xauthority